# AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath fails in .targets files

Tags: msbuild, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to centralize some of the build configurations for many projects, and MSBuild solution for this is to use [`.targets` files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-dot-targets-files).

One configuration that I'd like to apply to all projects, is to prevent `netcoreapp2.1` to append to all output directories. To achieve that all it takes is to include this one line of configuration:

```
<AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
```

However, when I place this line in a `Common.targets` file, and include that file in my `.csproj` file using `<Import Project="PathToCommonTargets" />`, then it has no effect and I still get the `netcoreapp2.1` at the end of my output folder.

How can I solve this?

**Reason Update:**
We are a company that is the technical partner for more than 10 other companies. That is, we have a central source control for the infrastructure (let's say mapped to `C:\Infra`), and for each company a distinct source control (let's say mapped to `C:\CompanyA` and `C:\CompanyB`, etc.), which might contain up to 100 solutions, each might containing more than 10 projects. So, our top-priority requirement is to reduce costs as much as we can through DRYing everything, from Angular, to Java, to Swift, and to .NET. Based on continuous improvement spirit, we don't want our outputs to be put in `\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1` for more than 2000 project files (and increasing) to reduce the time our developers spend going into the output folder and also make refactoring to higher versions of .NET easier and less expensive. To upgrade from `netcoreapp2.0` to `netcoreapp2.1` we had nightmares because of output paths in our automation. That's why we tried using `AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath`. But I'm really frustrated as why things should be this challenging. To me, MSBuild should FIRST LOAD EVERYTHING, and then start building. This way, a Boolean attribute would be present everywhere during build pipeline and won't be needing this much complexity to be configured. After all, what's the use of a Boolean attribute, if it takes more than `true/false` to configure it?

Comment: Please post the exact project file. this property is very sensitive as to where in the file the import statement is placed. Personally, I recommend creating a file named `Directory.Build.props` for such configuration properties and `Directory.Build.targets` for build logic (both are automatically included and you don't need import statements)

Answer (score 6):

> AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath fails in .targets files

The property `AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath` could stop MSBuild appending `TargetFramework` to `OutputPath`, but because the `TargetFramework` folder was already generated when we created the project, **we need to manually delete the TargetFramework folder** after adding the `<Import Project="PathToCommonTargets" />` to the project, otherwise that folder will always be there, then we could build the project without `TargetFramework` to `OutputPath`.

If the `TargetFramework` folder is still generated after it is deleted, you should double the content of `.targets` and the import statement are correct. To make sure them, I add a test custom target in the `.target` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <PropertyGroup>    
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath> 
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="Test" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Message Text="This is Test Custom Target!"></Message>
  </Target>

</Project>
```

When we build the project, and we could see the message info in the output window, that means the content of `.targets` and the import statement are correct.

**Update:**

> Could you please help me on how to delete TargetFramework?

To accomplish this, unload your project. Then at the very end of the project, just before the end-tag `</project>`, place below scripts:

```
<Target Name="RemoveDirectories" AfterTargets="Build">  
    <RemoveDir  
        Directories="$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)" /> 
</Target>
```

Besides, you need back up files in the `TargetFramework` to the bin\debug or bin\release folder, so we also need copy task before the remove task:

```
<ItemGroup>  
    <MySourceFiles Include="$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)\*.*"/>  
</ItemGroup> 

<Copy  
    SourceFiles="@(MySourceFiles)"  
    DestinationFolder="$(ProjectDir)bin\$(ConfigurationName)"  
 /> 

 <RemoveDir  
    Directories="$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. Could you please help me on how to delete `TargetFramework`? I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/removedir-task?view=vs-2017), but I can't find out how to use it and where to put it.

Comment: @mohammadrostamisiahgeli, pleasure, wait a few minutes, I will update the answer.

Comment: @mohammadrostamisiahgeli, updated it, check if it helps you.

Comment: As I understand, I have to add those lines inside my `.csproj` file, not inside my `.targets` file. I'm afraid this is not practical for me. I have more than 2000 `.csproj` files, and the MAIN reason I'm using `.targets` files is to centralize build definitions in one place. This defies that goal in the first place. I need to somehow solve this in that `.targets` file, not in `.csproj` level.

Comment: @mohammadrostamisiahgeli, Fortunately, you can add this in the .targets file, it works fine. Since you have 2000 .csproj files, you can use the Martin`s suggestion, use Directory.Build.targets in the solution folder.

Comment: @mohammadrostamisiahgeli, Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: Dear Leo, we tried your approach once and we couldn't make it work. Thus we dropped this issue for now, and decided to accept the hardship of upgrade for now. But if you need this data I gladly test it one more and provide you with the exceptions and problems.

Comment: FYI, I got the AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath setting to be respected by using a Directory.Build.props file. If you read the Microsoft documentation on this, you can see that .props files are loaded before .target files: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019