# Conditional AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath based on TargetFramework

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, msbuild

I'm trying to set `AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath` for a large number of projects, but depending on the TargetFramework.

So basically I have

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net48'">
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
    <AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>false</AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

and have to figure out where to put it so I don't have to duplicate code in all projects.

What I've figured out so far:

`Directory.Build.props`: If I don't specify a condition (`Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net48'"`) it works reliably. If I limit it to only a specific TargetFramework then it only works if the project is multi-targeting. I.e. `<TargetFrameworks>net48;net5.0</TargetFrameworks>` works fine, but for `<TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>` the condition evaluates to false - not too surprising since the Build.props file is evaluated before the TargetFramework is set in the csproj (also not too surprising that multi-targeting works, given how this is implemented).

`Directory.Build.targets`: While this would solve the problem with the TargetFramework not being set in the csproj, it seems like this is too late in the evaluation process and the output path is already set.

Is there any way around this apart from requiring all projects to use `<TargetFrameworks>`? (which would be an incredibly fragile solution).

Note that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53634727/appendtargetframeworktooutputpath-fails-in-targets-files) is NOT a duplicate, since the user is importing the common file manually in the csproj which gives you much finer control over when the definitions are imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `<BeforeTargetFrameworkInferenceTargets>` property to specify the path to a target file that is executed at the right time during the build.